# default value to element in xml

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an xml element whose contents are nothing but series of another element like this

```
<VARIABLES ID="1">
    <VAR NAME="COUNTER" VALUE="1" COMMENTS=" " />
</VARIABLES>
```

Now here I want to ensure that  element must have default element of type VAR whose NAME is "INVALID" and VALUE="-1". Can anyone please tell me how to do that? I tried defining simple type for each attribute NAME and VALUE and giving default to those attribute but the problem with that is that user can enter VAR of NAME equal to "INVALID" and VALUE other that -1 like 0.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If your requirement is to provide the default values you mention, then what is wrong with the fact that users can specify the default values explicitly?  Your real problem at the moment appears to be inability to identify your requirement clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you want to define a constraint on a certain element such that when `NAME="INVALID"` then it must also be the case that `VALUE="-1"`.

Those are called [co-occurrence constraints](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Co-occurrence_constraints).   As far as I know they are not supported at all in XML schema, and you'll need [Schematron](http://www.schematron.com/) in order to write a rule that accomplishes that.